# Git - nested repositories

Tags: git

I have a main project that has a component that comes from a separate remote repo that must also be updated/pushed in concert with the main project.  Not necessarily simultaneously (I'm *not* looking to have a push of the main project trigger a push of the component), but I should be able to push changes made to both the main project and component whenever I need to.

How can I make it so, with a structure abstractly like:

```
/root working directory of main project
    /some dir
        |
        |-> some file
        |
        |-> some file
    /component
        |
        |-> some file
        |
        |-> some file
        /subdir of component
```

Component will be tracked separately from the rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about Git submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules
I think it perfectly matches your needs.